# ThinkingSphinx: How to get the sphinxql SQL expression?

Tags: thinking-sphinx

`pancakes = Article.search 'pancakes'`

How would I then get the resultant underlying sphinxql expression?
Is it possible to just retrieve the expression without performing the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [Pat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54500/pat) on [github](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/1033):

> To find the SphinxQL statement, you can do the following:
>
> ```
> pancakes = Article.search 'pancakes'
> pancakes.populate
> pancakes.context[:sphinxql].to_sql
> ```
>
> However, if you want to get that without actually sending the query to
>   Sphinx, you'll want to send through a much more minimal middleware
>   stack:
>
> ```
> middleware = ::Middleware::Builder.new do
>   use ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::SphinxQL
> end
>
> pancakes = Article.search 'pancakes', :middleware => middleware
> pancakes.populate
> pancakes.context[:sphinxql].to_sql
> ```
>
> You can also send the `:populate => true` option through as part of
>   the search options instead of calling populate on the search object,
>   to save a line of code. TS search results are lazily loaded, hence the
>   need for that when accessing the context data.